# How to write a shell script that upon invocation shows the time and date and lists all the logged-in users.This information is then saved in a file

Tags: bash, shell

I need to list all the logged in users along with the date and time of log in. How can I do that using shell script?

```
#!/bin/bash
cat > log.log << EOF1
how to replace the bash command 'w' in here
EOF1
```

Comment: Why not just `w > log.log`??

Comment: This is more of an assignment actually. need to do it this way.

Comment: `eval $(printf "\x$(printf %x 87)" | tr 'A-Z' 'a-z') > log.log`

Comment: @SoumyaranjanAcharya : Why don't you just put the `w` command into a shell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **This is written for Mac, not tried in a linux machine.**

write this to `login.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
last |grep "logged in" > ./login.log
```

`touch login.log`

run `./login.sh`

Then `cat login.log` you can see

```
userA     ttys001                   Sun Jun  9 12:07   still logged in
userB     ttys000                   Sun Jun  9 11:53   still logged in
userC     console                   Sun Jun  9 11:49   still logged in
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use only `w > log.log` like *oguz ismail* writes, or you can write the output of w into a variable and display this variable in the here-document.

```
#!/bin/bash

w_content=$(w)
cat > log <<EOF
Headline
$w_content
Footer
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check below script, It will work your demand

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$(echo -e "current date and time :- \n $(date)\n"
echo -e "All logged in Users with details :- \n $(who)\n "
echo -e "Server uptime :-\n $(uptime |awk -F ',' '{print $1}') \n" 
echo -e "Script running entries are logged in log file /var/log/sh.log")
echo "$a" && echo "$a" >> /var/log/sh.log 2>&1
```